# Is there a good argument for why you can't place 4 queens which cover a chessboard?

Tags: co.combinatorics, chess

It has been known since the 1850's (or even much earlier) that 5 queens could be placed on an 8*8 
chessboard so that every square on the board lies in the same row, column, or diagonal as at least one
of the queens. It was also "known" that this could not be done with 4 queens. But I have not been able to
obtain or track down any rigorous mathematical proof of this that could be (or could have been) carried out
in a reasonable time by a human being with pencil and paper. There are altogether 635376 ways of placing
4 queens on an 8*8 chessboard. Does anyone know of a combinatorial algorithm, exploiting the symmetries of
the chessboard, which would reduce the number of cases to be considered to the hundreds (or, at most, the
low thousands.)?
                  This is, of course, a trivial problem for modern computers, which have many times since
verified that 5 queens are needed.

Comment: I'll start with the obvious trivial observation that doesn't get close at all.  The symmetry group of the square has 8 elements.  Supposing that a typical configuration of 4 queens has none of those symmetries, you reduce the number of configurations by about a factor of 8, so there are "only" roughly $10^6$ to consider. 

Comment: You might consider the subproblem of placing four queens on a chess board so that all the white squares are covered.  You may be able to argue that this is not possible unless at least three of the queens sit on white squares.  But now there are the black squares to worry about... .  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.07.02

Comment: Well... you need at least 3 since each queen can cover up to 32 squares.  And they cover at least one common square.  

Comment: Unfortunately, the above argument does not hold: You can place four queens so that all the squares of one color are covered.  However, you may be able to us this to show that any covering must have two queens on each color square, and then use that to limit the possibilities for covering the white squares.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.07.02

Comment: I wonder if the following naive approach might lead to a manageable number of cases: After placing a single queen somewhere, there are at least two uncovered 3x3 triangles left. You can cover them completely by placing queens in them, but if you do that for both, the remaining uncovered squares cannot be covered by a single queen. If you do it for one, the squares in the other triangle that are still not covered place some rather strong restrictions on the remaining two queens. Finally, if you place the second queen outside the two triangles, there are uncovered squares in both...

Answer (score 19):

The problem of finding the minimum number of queens needed to cover an n-by-n board is the queens domination problem.  According to http://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/15/ocr-ajc-v15-p145.pdf , "Although there is
currently no mathematical proof that these values [the known minimum numbers of queens] are correct, they have been verified by computer."

According to http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_8/PDF/v8i1r29.pdf ,
"...current knowledge that [among other things, the queens domination number for an 8-by-8 board is greater than 4], comes from exhaustive search."

Comment: That's a little strange: a computer calculation doesn't count as a mathematical proof? 

Comment: The calculation by itself, no.  The calculation can support, contribute to, or be a major part of a proof.  I think that some words are needed to make the link between the calculation and what the calculation supports, and the combination of words and calculation can then form a  mathematical proof.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.07.02

Comment: @Pete: perhaps the authors intend that a mathematical proof is one which, while may not deserve a place in The Book, has a place in A Scroll, or perhaps on A Few Sheets of Papyrus. :)

Comment: More citations: minimum dominating set of queens: A trivial programming exercise? http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1715994

Also: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(02)00802-6


Comment: Related sequences: http://oeis.org/classic/A075458 and http://oeis.org/classic/A075324

Comment: @PeteL.Clark In this case, the computer is not 'calculating' in the mathematical sense, but rather brute-forcing every possible combination, trivial for a computer, but which would take a human being a very long time.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I'm speaking as a software engineer, not a mathematician! Brute-forcing *is* trivial for a computer, since a machine can (for many problems) attempt thousands if not millions of combinations per second. Pure brute-force requires no cleverness (hence the name!) 'Cleverness' is what creates proper software algorithms to *avoid* brute-forcing, to improve performance. For the vast majority of software applications, brute-force operations are unacceptable, and more efficient solutions must be designed. However, I concede that mathematicians may have different definitions in their field

Answer (score 16):

The number of fundamental arrangements one needs to check to prove there is no solution with 4 queens is about  $\frac{1}{8}{64 \choose 4}\sim 10^5$ as Mark Meckes noted in his comment.

This number can be greatly reduced if we choose to inspect the space of solutions with $5$ queens. Clearly, every hypothetical $4$ queens' solution generates a family of $5$ queens' solutions (just place the $5$th queen at any of the $60$ remaining free squares).

Now, there are only $638$ fundamental arrangements with $5$ queens. All $4860$ solutions can be obtained from the fundamental arrangements by rotation and reflection. This was reportedly first calculated `by hand' by A.M. Yaglom and I.M. Yaglom (check out ["Across the Board: The Mathematics of Chessboard Problems"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xG2d-jPO5bcC&dq=Across+the+Board%3A+The+Mathematics+of+Chessboard+Problems&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=g6VJTOT6J9S5jAebz-S0Ag&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDIQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by John J. Watkins). It seems to be a pretty feasible task to check that one cannot remove a queen in any of those arrangements and still get a dominating arrangement.

Comment: Some of the suggestions for reducing the number of cases to be
considered are very interesting, especially the one based on the
638 fundamental solutions using 5 queens. But would this not also
require a proof that no arrangement of 5 queens (other than those
obtained by rotations and reflections from the 638 fundamental
solutions) could cover every square on the board.

Comment: I am a little puzzled by the estimate of Mark Meckes for the 
number of cases that need to be considered. It is stated to be
about !0^6 or even more. But I must be reading it incorrectly,
since the number of subsets of 4 elements contained in a set
of 64 elements is only 635376. 




Comment: @Garabed: That is roughly $10^{6}$...

Comment: That was a typo in my comment.  I meant $635376/8 \approx 10^5$.

Comment: @Garabed, re your first comment above: I think what Andrey is saying in part is that Yaglom and Yaglom provided the proof you're asking for.

Comment: Yes, several authors mention that the proof is due to Yaglom and Yaglom but I haven't managed to find the exact reference to a published version of the proof.

Comment: Paul Burchett in his 2005 Master's thesis (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.93.2184&rep=rep1&type=pdf)  cites A.M. Yaglom, I.M. Yaglom, Challenging mathematical problems with elementary
solutions. Volume 1: Combinatorial Analysis and Probability Theory 1964.  A Dover reprint of Yaglom and Yaglom is available through Amazon.com


Comment: @rdchat: Thank you for the comment. Actually, I've looked into the book and I did not find the result there!

Comment: @Andrey Rekalo:  On page 98 of the Dover edition, there is a statement that 5 is the minimum number of queens and that there are 4860 possible arrangements of 5 queens that cover the 8-by-8 board.  However, there is no "by hand" proof given for that statement, and I suspect the Yagloms didn't have one.

Comment: All right, so it is probably a side remark to a different problem because it's not listed as a separate problem in the book. At least, not in the Russian edition that I have looked into.

Comment: Somewhat remarkably 5 queens suffice to cover a 11x11 board!

Not sure when this was first observed or by whom.

Answer (score 5):

I also wonder whether the formation came before or after 1990, because that is when Spencer came up with the lower bound for n=11.  I know first-hand that formations can be searched for by hand for say, up to n=20 with reasonable results (note that is much different than actual proof that the formation is minimal, for if we find the formation we've only found an upper bound).  So it's quite possible that someone found the formation first, and then Spencer might have been the first to observe it.  Of course it's also possible that Spencer's bound came first.

I found Dr Chatham's comment interesting enough to vote it up, although seeing as how I'm stuck at one reputation, I can't.

Comment: Now you should be able to vote, I guess.