# Is the space of solutions to the Queens Domination Problem connected?

Tags: chess, co.combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

A configuration of queens on an 8 by 8 chessboard (or n by n if you like) is a *queen domination* if every square on the board lies in the same row, column, or diagonal as at least one of the queens. The Queens Domination Problem is to find the minimum number of queens necessary for a queen domination. A *solution* to the Queens Domination Problem is a queen domination using the minimum number of queens.

For the 8 by 8 chessboard, brute force has shown that 5 queens is the minimum number. More discussion about that [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30330/is-there-a-good-argument-for-why-you-cant-place-4-queens-which-cover-a-chessboar).

The adjacency relation on the set of solutions to the Queens Domination Problem is defined as follows: we say solutions are *adjacent* if they differ by only the placement of one queen. For example: C3, E4, D5, B6, F4 is adjacent to C3, E4, D5, B6, F2.

> How many equivalance classes are there in the equivalance relation generated by adjacency?

In other words, starting with one solution, can we reach any other solution by moving one queen at a time, such that the result of each move is itself a solution?

Comment: I get 4860 of them. I'll check to see if any obviously aren't adjacent to any others.

Comment: I just posted all of the solutions at http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~etressle/queens.txt. I was going to give you a list of coordinates, too, but I just typed ./a.out > main.cpp by accident, and so those are not going to be forthcoming.

Comment: Note that I am not the original asker, I was just helping him out. With coordinates it would be trivial to perform BFS, but alas... 

Comment: It's still not difficult, but I don't have time to parse that file right now and do it. I'll do it tonight if someone else hasn't.

Comment: You are a generous dude.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Revised and correct:

589 equivalence classes.

http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~etressle/classes.txt

It seems that the pairs (#vertices,#components) are (1,388) (2,100) (3,40) (4,34) (5,20) (18,4) (20,2) (3804,1) – damiano 15 hours ago

```
1: Class I.D. 2, 4, 5, 6, 7,..., 589.
2: Class I.D. 22, 29, 35, 47, 48,..., 579.
3: Class I.D. 28, 33, 38, 49, 58,..., 574.
4: Class I.D. 13, 90, 95, 126, 141,..., 576. 
5: Class I.D. 32, 37, 62, 89, 97,..., 395. 
18: Class I.D. 17, 31, 185, 303.
20: Class I.D. 3, 75.
3804: Class I.D. 1.
```

Comment: (I thought I was being clever by adding dollar signs to fill-up the 15 character minimum, but I forgot that you can't use latex in comments. Ho hum.)

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what the file means: is there a *huge* component and lots of tiny components?

Comment: You can use LaTeX... $i = \sqrt{-1}$

Comment: So in particular, 

CLASS 9:   (0,0)   (1,1)   (3,5)   (5,3)   (7,7)   

turns out to be one of many isolated solutions

Comment: It seems that the pairs (#vertices,#components) are 

(1,388) (2,100) (3,40) (4,34) (5,20) (18,4) (20,2) (3804,1)

Comment: @damiano: That seems to be the case. I didn't have enough time to process the file more than I had before I left earlier. Anyone is welcome to check my results from the queens.txt file, which I am certain is correct.